# mup and meteor resolving the url

Tags: meteor, deployment, digital-ocean, meteor-up

In my mup settings I have

```
  "env": {
     "ROOT_URL": "http://localhost",
      "PORT": 3000,
      "UPSTART_UID" : "meteoruser",
      "MAIL_URL": "smtp://username:password@smtp.sendgrid.net:587",
      "METEOR_ENV": "production"
   },
```

I am following this.

http://johngibby.com/blog/How_to_deploy_your_meteor.js_app_on_Digital_Ocean

Should the port be 3000 or 80 and should the URL be my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROOT_URL` should be the url of your DigitalOcean droplet, which leads to your app. For example, if your droplet has an IP of 83.132.230.12, you could do:

```
  "env": {
     "ROOT_URL": "http://83.132.230.12",
      "PORT": 3000,
      "UPSTART_UID" : "meteoruser",
      "MAIL_URL": "smtp://username:password@smtp.sendgrid.net:587",
      "METEOR_ENV": "production" }
```

But it will be quite impractical for visitors to connect to `http://83.132.230.12` in their web browser. It's better to [have a domain name assigned to your droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean), in order to do:

```
  "env": {
     "ROOT_URL": "http://www.yourdomainname.com",
      "PORT": 3000,
      "UPSTART_UID" : "meteoruser",
      "MAIL_URL": "smtp://username:password@smtp.sendgrid.net:587",
      "METEOR_ENV": "production" }
```

`PORT` should be the port on which you want people to access your app. For example, if you give a 3000 port, your app will be accessed through `http://www.yourdomainname.com:3000`, which looks also impractical. On the other hand, web browsers use port 80 by default. So if you use `"PORT": 80`, your app will be accessible through `http://www.yourdomainname.com` (no port required in the url)

Comment: The important bit was the "have a domain name assigned to your droplet" which I failed to do.